# S3 not reading relative paths?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

Hi I'm having some trouble getting a few parts of the CSS synced up for an app after loading static files to S3.  My icons and background image both dont load and I suspect it is because of the way the paths are routed.  In the style sheet they are both currently loaded as:

```
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");

background: url("../img/background.png");
```

This worked fine when I was loading static files hosted on my own computer.  I'm a little confused as to why this type of path doesn't load when loaded on S3.  The relative paths are all the same there.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the folder and images are publicly accessible. By default, S3 makes content private thus preventing the browser from loading your images.

Comment: man, love this place, pulled my hair out for an hour and you solved it for me in 3 seconds, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also, apart from giving the permissions , are you sure that your resultant url for image is

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>/img/background.png`

if not, you might want to make it this way. also you should have img folder inside bucket and yours files should be present in that folder.

Comment: S3 objects live in buckets, not directories. You are free to name your objects with a file path, and many tools will provide you a view of your data as though it was stored in a directory, but there is not an actual directory tree to reference.

Comment: yes, that is true, but you can give a logical directory structure by creating folders inside bucket.

Comment: Note that in March 2019, Amazon announced that the so-called "path styled" API is deprecated, and support will be dropped in September 30th, 2020. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=6776 and https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19821406